# Trocar titulo na ActionBar

Tags: android, animação

estou fazendo um app que possuí um Sliding Tab, aquela telinha q vc desliza para o lado ele tem várias telas. Esta funcionando e inclusive quando eu mudo de Tab, no Listener que detecta a mudança eu chamo a Activity e faço a mudança do titulo da ActionBar, funciona, mas minha duvida é o efeito de transição mais suave na troca no titulo. Esta ocorrendo de forma abrupta, no supetão, queria saber como colocar um fade nessa troca para ficar mais suavem igual ja vi em outros app.
Alguem sabe?

Answer (score 1):

achei uma solução no link logo depois de ter postado a pergunta aqui:
http://w9jds.github.io/walkthroughs/2016/03/09/animating_toolbar_title